# Type mismatch in signature and locally introduced term

Tags: haskell

Consider the following code:

```hs
-- | Parse a 64bit word in little-endian format.
word64le :: Get ByteString e Word64
word64le = do
    s <- elems 8
    pure $ foldl' (.|.) 0 [shiftL (fromIntegral b) (i * 8) | (i, b) <- zip [0 .. 7] (atomize s)]
```

Per the comment, this reads out a Word64 from a ByteString by first pulling an 8-byte ByteString (the `elems` call), then unpacking it (the `atomize` call) and doing the obvious shift left dance. So far so good. Now this code can very obviously be generalized to other machine integral types, we just need to get hold of the number of bits of such a type and that is supplied by the FiniteBits class. So doing the generalization:

```hs
-- | Parse an integral word in little-endian format.
integralLe :: (FiniteBits w, Integral w, Bounded w) => Get ByteString e w
integralLe = do
        s <- elems (fromIntegral n)
        pure $ foldl' (.|.) 0 [shiftL (fromIntegral b) (i * 8) | (i, b) <- zip [0 .. n - 1] (atomize s)]
    where
        n = finiteBitSize (minBound :: w) `quot` 8
```

This does not work, with GHC complaining that "Could not deduce (Bounded w1) arising from a use of ‘minBound’ from the context: (FiniteBits w, Integral w, Bounded w)". So it *seems* that my type annotation `minBound :: w` is not enough to convince GHC that I mean the same `w` as in the function signature; is my diagnosis correct? And if yes, how do I tell GHC that the two w types are the same?

note(s):

- on GHC 9.2 with a nightly stackage.
- sorry about the poor question title, but cannot think of anything better.

edit(s):

- per the comment added `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`  at the top of the file but having the same error, namely "Could not deduce (Bounded w2) arising from a use of ‘minBound’ from the context: (FiniteBits w, Integral w, Bounded w) bound by the type signature for:"
- Aha. If I add an explicit `forall e w .` in the function signature to the left of the constraint it works, even without the ScopedTypedVariables extensions (maybe because I am using language GHC2021). No on, to understand why the heck this works...

Comment: Use the `ScopedTypeVariable` extension.

Comment: Per the edit, enabling the extension does not seem to work.

Comment: Per the second edit, adding an explicit forall works. Hmm... my understanding is lacking as I thought naked type variables had an implicit forall. Thanks for the help. Will mark it solved if no one else chimes in.

Comment: ScopedTypeVariables requires the for all to be explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell has some... let's charitably call it "weird"... rules for how type variables are scoped by default.

```
-- | Parse an integral word in little-endian format.
integralLe :: (FiniteBits w, Integral w, Bounded w) => Get ByteString e w
integralLe = do
        s <- elems (fromIntegral n)
        pure $ foldl' (.|.) 0 [shiftL (fromIntegral b) (i * 8) | (i, b) <- zip [0 .. n - 1] (atomize s)]
    where
        n = finiteBitSize (minBound :: w) `quot` 8
```

You're right that Haskell will throw an implicit `forall w` at the start of the `integralLe` type signature, but it's not *actually* a `ScopedTypeVariables` forall. By default, the scope of that variable is just that one line. It is *not* considered a type variable inside of any type ascriptions or signatures in `where` clauses, `let` clauses, or anything else *inside* the function. That's where [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html) comes in. With `ScopedTypeVariables`, an *explicit* `forall` makes the type variable available lexically to anything inside of the function body, including `where` blocks. (And, as you've correctly noted, `ScopedTypeVariables` is included in `GHC2021`). Hence,

```
integralLe :: forall w. (FiniteBits w, Integral w, Bounded w) => Get ByteString e w
```

will work.